# Flutter apps displaying grey screen on apps start launch

Tags: flutter, build, background, build.gradle, splash-screen

I don't know if this is normal or a bug issue, I've noticed some apps (my own included)
after making a release version or even a debug one when launch it will display a weird bronze background color few milliseconds Screenshot below) is this normal on build or is there any resolution for this ?
Or perhaps could this be related to AndroidManifest

**Edit :** I'll post my build `gradle` and `AndroidManifest` in case it helps

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
```

> **AndroidManifest :**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android. permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
    </intent>
</queries>

<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="myapp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    >

    <receiver android:name="com.app.myapp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.page.link" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value=""/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value=""/>

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service            android:name="com.app.fayda.localnotifications.services.LocalNotificationsService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

[image: Screenshot app]

Here is another example of Tinder app which has the same issue right before `Splash screen` appear

[image: Screenshot tinder]

Comment: What device you're using and is the `dark-mode` enabled in your phone? I too get similar to this and its because of force `dark-mode` try disabling it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that just changed the color from grey to white lol

Comment: Yah it'll appear white, if you don't specify any splash screen image. Default splash screen is a solid white bg.

Comment: The issue is not about splash I do have splash displayed after the greey screen 
I may have found this issue working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few investigation I'll give some potential solution :

To check the logcat issue I had to change to release version  build variant

(1). Flutter clean and flutter pub get

(2). Open Android Module of Project in another window

(3). Wait for all process and after that First Clean Project and Rebuild Project

(4). Wait for Rebuild process complete and now change your build variants first at your left bottom you can see tab "Build variant" open it and after that in the front of "app" folder you can see in column of "Active Build Variant" like such "debug" please change it to "release"

(5). after that repeat step 3

(6) and run project from Android Module If you face the grey screen issue then you can know what is the exactly error in Logcat section and also make sure that your keystore file and keystore details are proper for release

This is another potential solution apparently this file `launch_background.xml` causing this every time you start the app it will launch this first and there's no way to bypass this as far as I know you may able to change the color as you see fit or put image but there's no workaround around this unfortunately